# Questions about LeetCode 148. Sort List

Tags: java, list, sorting

I know the getMid() method in the answer of approach 1 is like below.

```
public ListNode getMid(ListNode head) {
    ListNode midPrev = null;
    while (head != null && head.next != null) {
        midPrev = (midPrev == null) ? head : midPrev.next;
        head = head.next.next;
    }
    
    ListNode mid = midPrev.next;
    midPrev.next = null;
    return mid;
}
```

I tried this code before:

```
public ListNode getMid(ListNode head) {

    // This line is different from the answer.
    ListNode midPrev = head;
    
    while (head != null && head.next != null) {
    
        // This line is different from the answer.
        midPrev = midPrev.next;
        
        head = head.next.next;
    }
    
    ListNode mid = midPrev.next;
    midPrev.next = null;
    return mid;
}
```

And then I get this Runtime Error:

WARNING: A command line option has enabled the Security Manager

Can anyone tell me why the midPrev = head is wrong?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code.  The warning that you're reporting is probably unrelated to anything in your code.  As for whether your code is wrong, it's a bit hard to tell when you haven't told us what problem you're trying to solve.  Perhaps you can paste the problem statement into this question.

Comment: your code is fine, just need to tune your JVM settings, probably your IDE did that for you.